Multi Layer Alpha issue
I'm digging into Multi Layer rendering and putting them back together with alpha overs, but I've got a small issue where on one layer the alpha is still visible on the fringe of that layer, in the image you can see if on the bottom right on the black edge.
It's the closest part to the camera so I've put that last in the node layering (apart from volumetrics as that needs to be last or it looks real weird). Any thoughts on this? Or is this not going to be an issue when I do this properly in Davinci?

Here is my comp node setup:

